# Does React block users from finding components behind login?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, security

I'm new to React and am working on an app that requires user authentication. I have my authentication working fine, basically with redux keeping track of an `isSignedIn` piece of state, which defaults to false. If false, the user is shown a login form, and if true, the user is shown whatever else they need to see. The login form uses axios to send a post to a server-side authentication script, which responds with a JSON object that includes whether the user is valid or not, and the reducer sets `isSignedIn` accordingly.

I'm curious though, since the entire app is client-side javascript, can't a nefarious user somehow un-pack the script and modify it locally so they can see the components that normally don't render unless logged in?

Some relevant code snippets from the main `App` component...

`render:`

```
render(){
    return (
        <div className="ui container">
            {
                this.props.isSignedIn &&
                <Navigation pathname={this.props.pathname} />
            }
            {
                !this.props.isSignedIn &&
                <Login />
            }
        </div>
    );
}
```

`mapStateToProps:`

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        isSignedIn: state.isSignedIn
    };
};
```

Comment: Right, but the components are useless without data. So, you have to protect the rest api or whatever you have as backend. Use an auth token granted on successful login to call the backend. There are many standard ways of doing this.

Comment: Thanks @rodrigoap. My backend does check authentication on all requests from the app, so that part should be in good shape. But what if I want my components to display data that should be private, such as `today we had 10,000 orders for our top-secret awesome item that we don't want our competition to know about`.. I guess I just shouldn't do that?

Comment: @MikeWillis that type of info should be restricted to privileged users, so only users with the privledged auth credentials (e.g., `internal` users) can access that info. Even if the route is know, other users cannot access it without privileged auth even if they know the api route. Other users can see your component and how it transforms the data but with privledged auth they cannot see the data it would display.

Comment: @HarleyLang so basically all private data should be supplied via JSON by server-side scripts that verify user authentication? Everything else should be considered visible to the end user (paths, path names, structure, etc)?

Comment: @MikeWillis You can try to obfuscate your front end code but if someone wants your api routes or components, they can reverse engineer your client-side code. That's the magic of the web: everything is public on the client side for you to inspect.